# Can I intercept phone dialing?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, phone-call, intercept

I would like to listen on the user's phone dialing. If I recognize that the dialed number is something that my app defined as a non-real-call (like starting with #####) I would like to cancel the call and start my own application. This is doable in Android. Can it be done on iPhone?

Thanks,
 Simon

Comment: I think you have to hack the iOS system...maybe this is possible if you make a Jailbreak application but on an legal iOS application I dont think this is possible.

Comment: why you want to do this? custom URL scheme is good enough.

Comment: @Noah, not saying I endorse this, but a Jail-broken system is legal. The electronic frontier foundation successfully argued its legality a number of years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why you would want to to this. Eg dialing a special number to direct the call through an internet service instead of the main network.

It is not however possible on standard (ie non-jail-broken) iOS. You can get something similar with URL schemes.